# std::unordered_map pointers/reference invalidation

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, unordered-map

I have the following code:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map;

map["k1"] = "v1";
auto& v1 = map["k1"];
map["k2"] = "v2";
```

After reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map#Notes

> Notes
>
> The swap functions do not invalidate any of the iterators inside the container, but they do invalidate the iterator marking the end of the swap region.
>
> References and pointers to either key or data stored in the container are only invalidated by erasing that element, even when the corresponding iterator is invalidated.

It looks like `v1` can be safely used after inserting new values, even if re-hashing might occur during insertion.

Is my interpretation of this quote correct? May I use references/pointers of the values from the map after modifying the map (obviously erasing the value itself would invalidate the reference/pointer)?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> It looks like `v1` can be safely used after inserting new values, even if re-hashing might occur during insertion.

Yes, [`std::unordered_map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) doesn't invalidate references, even rehashing happens.

(emphasis mine)

> If an insertion occurs and results in a rehashing of the container, all iterators are invalidated. Otherwise iterators are not affected. **References are not invalidated**.

From the standard, [[unord.req]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/unord.req#general-9):

(emphasis mine)

> Rehashing invalidates iterators, changes ordering between elements, and changes which buckets elements appear in, but **does not invalidate pointers or references to elements**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868640/stdunordered-map-pointers-reference-invalidation 
`If rehashing occurs (due to the insertion), all iterators and references are invalidated`

Comment: @QingchuanZhang You mean my quotes from cppreference.com and standard are wrong?

Comment: I feel they are conflicting, cppreference says `If rehashing occurs (due to the insertion), all iterators and references are invalidated`
and the standard says `Rehashing invalidates iterators, changes ordering between elements, and changes which buckets elements appear in, but does not invalidate pointers or references to elements`

Comment: @QingchuanZhang The standard is always correct. cppreference.com is just a wiki-based website.